How to make an EQ soundbar with Geometry nodes
How can I make an EQ soundbar with Geometry nodes? I would like to be able to determine how many bars are visible going up and down, if I can have 10 or 20 or 30 bars, and with the classic gradient colour, green to red.

Would it also be possible to use a simple deform on geometry nodes, to achieve this as well?


What part are you struggling with ? Gradient of color on multiple squares, connect audio amplitude to geometry nodes, something else ?

One sound bar doesn’t make a spectrogram. Do you just want a volume meter?

A shader would be easier than geometry nodes... can a shader be used instead?

I have made an animation using array modifier, but there's not much control, animating the speed of the bars,  also it leaves one bar always visible on count 1,where it should be 0. So I thought geometry nodes seems more intuitive to use. But Id like to see what other options the community has to offer.
Keep it mind, this soundbar will not be animating with sound within Blender.
https://ibb.co/J2HZSvS

Here, a customizable shader solution with:

Value for box count
Value for lit box count
Customizable division border size
Customizable top border size
Customizable side border size


The bend modifier will work as long as you don't "apply" it:

Some comments:

Used "generated" coordinates because they're assured to be between 0 and 1, making it easy to have constant values in the nodes
When using generated, you need to follow the actual axes of the object (disregarding its rotation). In this case, Y and Z
You can use other coordinates, such as "object" or "UV", but then you'd have to adjust the values accordingly, and it would be harder to work with ramps, since you'd have to normalize the fac values.
I used multiplications for masking the borders (knowing that 0 = black), but you can use "mix color" or "mix shader" nodes instead if you want the borders to be different from black
I plugged the color straight to the surface output for visualization, but you can use a BSDF shader, no problem.

About animation:

You can create attributes via geometry nodes ("Store Named Attribute") and use them in the shader ("Attribute")
You can use custom attributes
You can right click the "value" node and insert keyframes


Thanks for your time and effort setting up the nodes!
